# C function that removes comments from input

Tags: c, function, comments

I am new to C and trying to write my own function in C that would clean the comments out of a given input code. However there is some error with my logic as the result is not even close to desired.

My code is as follows:

```
char *removeComments(char *in)
{
    int i;
    int multipleLineFlag = 0;
    int singleLineFlag = 0;
    int n = strlen(input);
    char* output = malloc(n * sizeof(char));

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (in[i] == '/' && in[i+1] == '*')
        {
            i++;
            multipleLineFlag = 1;
        }
        else if (multipleLineFlag == 1 && in[i] == '*' && in[i+1] == '/')
        {
            i++;
            multipleLineFlag = 0;
        }
        else if (in[i] == '/' && in[i+1] == '/')
        {
            i++;
            singleLineFlag = 1;
        }
        else if (singleLineFlag == 1 && in[i] == '\n')
        {
            singleLineFlag = 0;
        }
        else if (multipleLineFlag == 0 && singleLineFlag == 0)
        {
            out[i] = in[i];
        }
        i++;
    }    
    free(in);
    return out;
}
```

Anybody else able to find my error in the code?

Comment: Please show an example of input, actual output and expected output.

Comment: The output with the posted version is just empty.
Example input would be
    /* Hello World program */  
      
    #include<stdio.h>  
      
    main()  
    {  
        printf("Hello World");  
      
    }  
Where the function is expected to remove the commented line from the top.

Comment: Your code isn't correctly handling `/*` embedded in strings...

Comment: You did not terminate your `out` string. Also `out` and `output` are 2 different variables and only 1 is declared.

Comment: @C.Robinson for clarifications, please don't put them in comments but edit your question.

Comment: Among other problems: `char* output = malloc(n * sizeof(char))` should be `char* output = malloc((n + 1) * sizeof(char))` because you need one byte more for the NULL string terminator.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious problem with your code is with this line:

```
out[i] = in[i];
```

You need to use 2 different variables to track where you are in the input and output strings as they'll be different. For example if the input string contains "foo /* test */ bar", then the output should contain "foo  bar", but what you'd actually get currently is "foo [10 undefined characters] bar". If you're lucky those undefined characters would be NULs.

The other problem is you're not adding a NUL to the end of the output. Which you'd be hard pressed to do if the input contains no comments as you're not allocating enough space - so as well as added the NUL at the end, you also need to allocate 1 more char than you are currently.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the problem identified by Chris and Antti, you should be aware that you cannot just parse the comment syntax to remove comments from C source code, you must also parse the string syntax to avoid false matches occurring inside string literals.

There is also this special case:

```
// this is a single line comment\
broken on 2 lines
```

And this one:

```
/\
*\
This is a block comment
*\
/
```

A state machine seems a correct approach for this problem, but state machines can be very tricky to polish.

Another point that is important to remember: block comments should be replaced with a single space character, otherwise you may have old style token pasting which is incorrect:

`int/**/res;` should expand to `int res;`, not `intres;`

Comment: Good point about parsing the string syntax as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're sharing the *same* index for input and output - it means the `out[0]` to `out[strlen("/* Hello World program */" - 1]` will be *uninitialized*, and probably `malloc` just gives zeroed memory - thus the first character in your `out` would be a NUL character that terminates the string.

Actually you shouldn't be using indexes at all here, just use pointers.

```
char *result = malloc(n);
char *out = result;

...
    * out++ = in[i];
... 
// finally terminate the output
*out = '\0';
return result;
```

Likewise, I'd prefer writing the `in` part of the code using just pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation. Solved the issue together with the other answers!

Answer (score 0):

Typically I would approach such a task with a state machine.

Here is an untested example of what I am talking about:

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef enum {
  CODE,
  SLASH,
  SINGLELINE,
  MULTILINE,
  MULTILINE_ASTER
} state_t;

char* remove_comments(char const*in) {
  size_t len = strlen(in);
  char *out = malloc(len + 1);
  memset(out, 0, len+1);
  char c;
  state_t state = CODE;
  size_t opos = 0;
  while ((c = *in++)) {
    switch (state) {
    case CODE:
      if (c == '/') {
        state = SLASH;
      } else {
        out[opos++] = c;
      }
      break;
    case SLASH:
      switch (c) {
      case '/':
        state = SINGLELINE;
        break;
      case '*':
        state = MULTILINE;
        break;
      default:
        // this is a syntax error
        break;
      }
      break;
    case SINGLELINE:
      if (c == '\n') {
        state = CODE;
      }
      break;
    case MULTILINE:
      if (c == '*') {
        state = MULTILINE_ASTER;
      }
      break;
    case MULTILINE_ASTER:
      switch (c) {
      case '/':
        state = CODE;
        break;
      case '*':
        break;
      default:
        state = MULTILINE;
      }
    }
  }
  return out;
}

int main() {
  printf("%s", remove_comments("/********************************\n\
        * main function\n\
        * argc - number of arguments passed\n\
        * argv - pointer tgo arguments array\n\
        ********************************************/\n\
        int main(int argc, char **argv) {\n\
          // return number of arguments as return code\n\
          return argc;\n\
        }\n"));
  return 0;
}
```

---

Forgot to mention this code won't play along with string literals, these need to have their own states.